# custom attr selector in jquery not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select and hide the highlighted element. It has a custom attribute of `data-role="end"`.

[image: Example of DOM code]

I tried this,

```
$('.popover-navigation .btn-group .btn[data-role="end"]').css('display','none');
```

but it doesn't hide the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`.btn[data-role="end"]` is not a child of the class `.btn-group`** So your code won't work. Instead, try the code below:

```
$('.popover-navigation .btn[data-role="end"]').css('display','none');
```

Answer (score 1):

`.btn` is not a **child** of `.btn-group`, but rather a **sibling**. Try

```
$('.popover-navigation .btn-group').next('.btn[data-role="end"]').css('display','none');
```

or, since your navigating from parent

```
$('.popover-navigation .btn[data-role="end"]').css('display','none');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try change to :**

```
$('.popover-navigation button[data-role="end"]').css('display','none');
```

**or**

```
$('.popover-navigation button[data-role="end"]').hide();
```

Comment: This won't work, as the desired element is not a child of `.btn-group`.

Comment: OMG.. did't realize that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This code will hide that particular button.
Try this

```
$('button[data-role="end"]').hide();
```

OR

```
$('button[data-role="end"]').css('display','none');
```

Both above code will work.